# Not able to exchange object/ timeout a child process using multiprocessing.Process() Python

Tags: python, timeout, python-multiprocessing

From the main process I am spawning a new process using `multiprocessing.Process`.

My aim is to do a heavy CPU intensive task in the child process and if the task takes too long (using `timeout_in` variable) to finish, then terminate it with a response else compute and get back the result from this task in the child process.

I am able to terminate if it is taking too long, but I am not able to get the object (`result`) in case of no forced termination of child process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

def do_threading(function,argument, timeout_in=1):

    # Making a queue for data exchange
    q = Queue()

    # Start function as a process
    p = Process(target=function, args=(argument,q,))
    p.start()

    # Wait for 10 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(timeout_in)

    # If thread is still active
    if p.is_alive():
        print("running... let's kill it...")

        # print(q.get())

        # Terminate
        p.terminate()

        p.join()

def do_big_job(argument, q):

    # Do something with passed argument
    print(argument)

    # heavy computation
    result = 2**1234567
    # print("in child thread ",result)

    # Putting result in the queue for exchange
    q.put(result)

def main_2():
    print("Main thread starting...")
    do_threading( do_big_job, "Child thread starting...", timeout_in=10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_2()
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use to get the result?

Comment: `result = 2**1234567` , For time being this is the sample computation. Later it would be some function from pyeda library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem come from the fact that you create the `Queue` inside `do_threading`. So when your calculation runs normally (no timeout), the function is terminated and the queue with it.

Here is an alternative code that works if there is no timeout:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

def do_threading(q,function,argument, timeout_in=1):

    # Start function as a process
    p = Process(target=function, args=(argument,q,))
    p.start()

    # Wait for 10 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(timeout_in)
    print "time out"
    # If thread is still active
    if p.is_alive():
        print("running... let's kill it...")

        # print(q.get())

        # Terminate
        p.terminate()
        print "terminate"
        p.join()

def do_big_job(argument, q):

    # Do something with passed argument
    print(argument)

    # heavy computation
    result = 2**123
    # print("in child thread ",result)

    # Putting result in the queue for exchange
    q.put(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue() # Creating the queue in the main allows you to access it anytime
    print("Main thread starting...")
    do_threading( q, do_big_job, "Child thread starting...", timeout_in=10)
    if q.empty():
        pass
    else:
        print(q.get()) # get your result here.
```

Comment: The problem is to obtain the value we have put in the Queue in case the code didn't time out.
Where to put that part? i.e. `print(q.get())`

Comment: I added the line at the end

Comment: The code is getting stuck when it is timing out doesn't end. I think there is nothing in the Queue to get.

Comment: I fixed it by checking if queue is empty ;)

Comment: By returning a Flag from `do_threading()` I am able to call `q.get()` when needed and this solved my problem. I didn't think about the scope of the Queue object. Thanks.
Your approach is far better, I feel dumb ;). Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch timeout exception in `queue` instead of process, for example:

```
...
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty
... 
def do_threading(q,function,argument, timeout_in=1):

    # Start function as a process
    p = Process(target=function, args=(argument,q,))
    p.start()

    try:
        print(q.get(True, timeout_in))
    except Empty:
        print "time out"
        p.terminate()

    p.join()
```

or you can able got result in `else` from your code:

```
...
# If thread is still active
if p.is_alive():
    print("running... let's kill it...")

    # Terminate
    p.terminate()

else:
    print(q.get())
```

Comment: The first approach is not timing out when given a timeout_in value as 1 sec (it should timeout) and it is also accepting only integral value.
The second approach is timing out always.

Comment: About first: why not? I blocked main process until got result or occurred provided timeout.

Comment: It is not timing out. I provided `result = 2**1234567` and `timeout_in = 1`, then also it didn't timeout. It took it's time and printed the result whereas I expected it to timeout due to crossing 1 second.